# Lost JbossFuse console

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I use to start JbossFuse with

```
cd /user/lib/jboss-fuse
bin/fuse
```

But I accidentally closed my Terminal, and now I get an error:

```
sindre@selite:/usr/lib/jboss-fuse$ bin/fuse
karaf: There is a Root instance already running with name root and pid 2176
```

How can I get into the Jboss Fuse console again?

Comment: If you didn't kill the process (just detached it from virtual terminal), try `bin/client` - you'll connect to running process and see the console

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the process with pid `2176` still running?  You can check it by doing:

```
$ jps -l
```

If you can see the process is still running, then the following command should stop it:

```
$ ./bin/stop
```

UPDATE:

As Grzegorz and Claus pointed out, there is the `bin/client` command that brings you back to the console from another terminal. Here is the documentation that explains it for more detail:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/configuring_and_running_jboss_fuse/esbruntimeconnect#ESBRuntimeConnectCommand

Comment: I dont want to stop Jboss Fuse. I want to get in back to the console.

Comment: I think there is a bin/client command you can use to connect as a client, if not then you can also connect via standard SSH. I think the jboss fuse documentation has something about that

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use the bin/client or other ssh client you can get the console back.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to connect to console from another (or the same) host through ssh:

```
ssh [login]@[fuse host ip] -p 8101
```

(example: `ssh admin@10.10.50.13 -p 8101`)